# Where can I get a list of new businesses that are created in the US?

Tags: api, business

I'm interested in new businesses in my area. Is there a way to get a list of new (physical) businesses that are created in my area, either as they open shop or ideally, even before? Any gov API that can do this? This is in the U.S.

Comment: Is there [nothing in here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+business)? As long as the data have an opening date it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are public resources available to access information on companies created in the US.

You can view open data of 500 companies in the US [here](http://www.opendata500.com/us/list/) 
Additionally, you can use [Data.gov](https://www.data.gov/)for more broad access to data.

For global company data, we've open sourced our 7+ Million Companies dataset which you can [download here](https://www.peopledatalabs.com/company-dataset?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=company-dataset).